# Reducer that updates multiple parts of the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Effectively, I need to update `state.litres` everytime I update `state.thickness`. How do I do that? (I'm using the word "state" to mean the redux store)

Here is my reducer:

```
export const thickness = (
  initialThickness: Map<*, *> = initialState.get('thickness'), 
  action: Object) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_THICKNESS': {
      const litres = calcVol(action.payload.state)
      let newThickness = initialThickness
        .set('thickness' + action.payload.number, action.payload.value)
      return newThickness
    }
    default:
      return initialThickness
  }
}
```

`litres` is something I have just added in then, and I would like to return it as well as `newThickness` - which is my attempt to update `state.litres` when I update `state.thickness`.

Bonus points if you can give an opinion on this: to calculate the litres, I needed access to the whole state (redux store) to pass to `calcVol(state)` (which calulates and returns the volume in litres). Is passing the whole state in the `action` like this, so that I can use it in the `reducer`, performant? Or is there a more performant way?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateThickness: (text, number, state) => {
    dispatch(updateDimension('thickness', text, number, state))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer like this cannot update both `thickness` and `litres` as it can only affect the node it is responsible for (`thickness` in this case).  You can either:

1. move the reducer up a level and have it own both the `thickness` and `litres` nodes i.e. `initialState = { thickness: 0, litres: 0 }`
2. have the `litres` reducers also handle the `UPDATE_THICKNESS` action type and update `litres` accourdingly.

However, there is no reason that you can't also dispatch an `'UPDATE_LITRES'` action as well.  If you are using a middleware like [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) then this is even easier and as you can do dispatch both from the same thunk, and it can also remove the need to pass the whole state in the action (which I wouldn't recommend, but have no numbers to back it up with).

```
const setThickness = (number, value) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_THICKNESS': payload: { number, value } })

        let litres = calcVol(getState())
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LITRES': payload: { number, value: litres } })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.